# Save data to ManyToManyField error in django?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, addition

this is the model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    questionbody = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('question post date')
```

and this is the view.py

```
    stags = request.POST['tag']
    ltags = stags.split(',')
    q = Question(
        question = request.POST['question'],
        questionbody = request.POST['questionbody'],
        author = request.user,
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        )
    q.save();

    for i in ltags:
        # print i        ouyput:jquery

        # print type(i)  ouyput:unicode

        # s = Tag.objects.get(name=i)
        s = Tag.objects.get(name='jquery')

        q.tags.add(s)
```

as u can see the 'tag' input is in 'string , string' format string, so i change it to a list (ltags),

but in the for loop when i try to add the tags like

```
s = Tag.objects.get(name=i)
```

to question,there is an error says

```
" Tag matching query does not exist ".
```

but when i use s = Tag.objects.get(name='jquery'), it works.

please help!

Comment: You sure that `i` doesn't contain any extra characters like space?

Comment: Have you tried using a list of tag instances

Comment: Maybe it's failing on an item in `ltags` other than jquery? Leave the `print i` in there, and see which tag is the last one processed before the error.

Comment: thank u Rohan, it does contain space

Answer (score 0):

my bad, it turns out the 'i' does contain a trailing space, again i'm sorry